Duplicate Collection error with Melvis and Haystack
I am using Milvus as document store with Haystack.
MilvusDocumentStore connection object called with:
@lru_cache
def get_vector_db():
    # Get document store from database
    return MilvusDocumentStore(
        connection_args={
            "uri": get_settings().milvus_db_path
        },  # Milvus Lite
        drop_old=True
    )

And the Haystack pipeline defined as below:
 file_type_router = FileTypeRouter(
        mime_types=[
            "text/plain"
        ]
    )
    # Converter plain text files to Document objects
    text_converter = TextFileToDocument()
    # Join Documents coming from different branches of a pipeline
    document_joiner = DocumentJoiner()
    # Clean the text of the documents
    document_cleaner = DocumentCleaner()
    # Split the documents into smaller documents
    document_splitter = DocumentSplitter(split_by="sentence", split_length=2)
    # Create embeddings from the Documents
    document_embedder = SentenceTransformersDocumentEmbedder(
        model="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2"
    )
    # Write the documents to the DocumentStore
    document_writer = DocumentWriter(document_store, policy=DuplicatePolicy.NONE)

    # Build the Indexing pipeline
    preprocessing_pipeline = Pipeline()
    preprocessing_pipeline.add_component(
        name="file_type_router", instance=file_type_router
    )
    preprocessing_pipeline.add_component(name="text_converter", instance=text_converter)
    preprocessing_pipeline.add_component(
        name="document_joiner", instance=document_joiner
    )
    preprocessing_pipeline.add_component(
        name="document_cleaner", instance=document_cleaner
    )
    preprocessing_pipeline.add_component(
        name="document_splitter", instance=document_splitter
    )
    preprocessing_pipeline.add_component(
        name="document_embedder", instance=document_embedder
    )
    preprocessing_pipeline.add_component(
        name="document_writer", instance=document_writer
    )

    # Connect components
    preprocessing_pipeline.connect(
        "file_type_router.plain/text, "text_converter.sources"
    )
    preprocessing_pipeline.connect("text_converter", "document_joiner")
    preprocessing_pipeline.connect("document_joiner", "document_cleaner")
    preprocessing_pipeline.connect("document_cleaner", "document_splitter")
    preprocessing_pipeline.connect("document_splitter", "document_embedder")
    preprocessing_pipeline.connect("document_embedder", "duplicate_checker")
    preprocessing_pipeline.connect(
        "duplicate_checker.documents_to_index", "document_writer.documents"
    )

When I try to write to the db I get the following error:
    Failed to create collection: HaystackCollection error: <MilvusException: 
    (code=2000, message=Assert "!name_ids_.count(field_name)" at 
    /Users/zilliz/milvus-lite/thirdparty/milvus/internal/core/src/common/Schema.h:172
    => duplicated field name: segcore error)>
    ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application

Following the error with the debugger seems like there is an attempt to recreate the default database collection.

Do you have duplicated field name?

What is name of the milvus collection here?

From the code of haystack_milvus if you don't specify name it uses "HaystackCollection". Not sure what you mean by "field name". Im trying to convert a plan text file to vectors, i havent specified any schema or anything. I believe the problem is that during document write the haystack code tries to recreate the collection.

field name is the name of each schema in the collection, and these names should be unique. it seems that you have used unique names.
